# How to determine derived class at run time and allow call to polymorphic method

Tags: c#, polymorphism, derived-class

I have a function which accepts two base class parameters. Within this function I wish to test the types of these parameters over a number of derived classes and then call a polymorphic function. See below to see my first attempt which won't compile.

```
    public static double Intersect(baseClass s0, baseClass s1)
    {
          if (s1 is derivedClassB) return (s0 as derivedClassA).PolyMethod((derivedClassB)s1);

          else if (s1 is derivedClassC) return (s0 as  derivedClassA).PolyMethod((derivedClassC)s1);
                    else return 0.0;

    }
```

I thought i could use something like

```
Type dType = s0.GetType();
(s0 as dType).PolyMethod(derivedClassB) s1);
```

but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Sorry something went wrong in my attempted simplification...think its formatted ok now

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use the built-in support for polymorphic methods in C#?  The *virtual* keyword?

Comment: I have used virtual in my definition of the PolyMethod in my base class....this is just an issue in a single use static method which i'm using to handle the different types. I'm using virtual and override for PolyMethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your base class like this

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    public abstract double PolyMethod(BaseClass s);
}
```

Define derived classes like this

```
public DerviedClassX : BaseClass
{
    public override double PolyMethod(BaseClass s)
    {
        return 0.0; // Return something usefull here.
    }
}
```

Then your method can be simplified like this

```
public static double Intersect(BaseClass s0, BaseClass s1)
{
    return s0.PolyMethod(s1);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here, however this [SO answer on virtual dispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165003/880990) and the link provided there to Eric Lippers arcticle on double dispatch might help you.

Comment: Thanks...simple when you know how.

Comment: No this is what i'm looking for...in fact my example is a little more complicated than what i presented here but i was just getting confused because i had two parameters varying over types. In fact it just boiled down to being this simple, working fine now.

Comment: OK. One note so. You can also use `virtual` methods instead of `abstract` methods, if the base class can provide a useful base implementation of the method.

Comment: Thanks, yes in this case it can't. I also realised i don't even need this static method I can just use s0.PolyMethod(s1) and have different methods for different (derivedClass) parameters s1.